$F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^m \big( \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} x_j\big)^2 \overset{?}{\Leftrightarrow} F$ is a positively semi-definite.
Main question. $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^m \big( \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} x_j\big)^2 \overset{?}{\Leftrightarrow} F$ is a positively semi-definite form of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. It's possible that $c_{ij} \ne c_{ji}$. All numbers are real.
What do I know?. It's obvious that if $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^m \big( \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} x_j\big)^2$ then it's nonnegative and thus $F$ is a positively semi-definite form.
Now suppose that $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is a positively semi-definite form. Then there's a linear transformation $\vec{y} = Q\vec{x}$ such that $F = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i^2$. We may put $z_i = \sqrt{a_i}y_i$ or $z_i = \sqrt{-a_i}y_i$ and get $F(\vec{z}(\vec{x})) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{\sigma_i} z_i^2$, where $\sigma_i = \{-1,1\}$. It looks like there's some theorem that states that $\sigma_i = 1$, because it would be strange if some of them is $-1$ in $F(\vec{z}(\vec{x}))$ but $F(x)$ is positively semi-definite. The question looks like smth.well-known.
Question 2: is it almost obvious that $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^m \big( \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} x_j\big)^2 \overset{?}{\Leftrightarrow} F$ is a positively semi-definite form?
Question 3: is there some theorem to prove it immediately?

Supposing we are working with real numbers, any symmetric positive (semi)definite matrix can be written as $M=A^TA$ and $F(x) = x^TA^TAx$

@Exodd
Did I undestand you right that if we have $x^{\top}Ax$ and want to show that $x^{\top}Ax = \sum_i y_i^2 = \vec{y}^{\top}\vec{y}$ for some $y = Cx$,  than we notice that $x^{\top}Ax =(Cx)^{\top}Cx = x^{\top}C^{\top} Cx$ and hence it's sufficient to just put $y = \sqrt{A}x$, and then the claim is obvious?

any quadratic bilinear and positive semidefinite form $F$ is represented by a positive semidefinite matrix $M$ as $F(x) = x^TMx$ but any such $M$ has a decomposition (for example the Cholesky decomposition, but also the square root) as $M=C^TC$, so $y = Cx$ works

Thank you very much!
